# Difficulty with the replace method

Tags: python, replace

I must have the user enter a date in `mm/dd/yy` format and then output the string in long-date format like `January, ##, ####`. I cannot for the life of me **get the month to replace as a the word.**

```
def main():
    get_date=input('Input a date in mm/dd/yy format!\nIf you would like to enter a 1-digit number, enter a zero first, then the number\nDate:')
    month= int(get_date[:2])
    day=int(get_date[3:5])
    year=int(get_date[6:])

    validate(month, day, year)#validates input

    get_month(get_date)

def validate(month,day,year):
    while month>12 or month<1 or day>31 or day<1 or year!=15:
        print("if you would like to enter a one-digit number, enter a zero first, then the number\n theres only 12 months in a year\n only up to 31 days in a month, and\n you must enter 15 as the year")
        get_date=input('Input a date in mm/dd/yy format!:')
        month= int(get_date[:2])
        day=int(get_date[3:5])
        year=int(get_date[6:])

def get_month(get_date):
    if get_date.startswith('01'):
        get_date.replace('01','January')
        print(get_date)
```

I have tried a plethora of things to fix this but I cannot make *January* appear instead of *01*.

Comment: [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) with something like 08/11/85 causes a  `SyntaxError` unless the user is careful to quote their input. I think you meant to use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input),

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Python are *immutable*, they don't change once they're created. That means any function that modifies it must *return* a new string. You need to capture that new value.

```
get_date = get_date.replace('01','January')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (and simplify the code) using python's date module.

The strptime function will parse a date from a string using format codes.  If it's can't parse it correctly, it will raise a value error, so no need for your custom validation function

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

The strftime function will print out that date formatted according to the same codes.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime

Updated, your code would look something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

parsed = None
while not parsed:
    get_date=input('Input a date in mm/dd/yy format!\nIf you would like to enter a 1-digit number, enter a zero first, then the number\nDate:')
    try:
        parsed = datetime.strptime(get_date, '%m/%d/%y')
    except ValueError:
        parsed = None


print parsed.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use datetime module ?

```
year = 2007; month=11; day=3
import datetime
d = datetime.date(year, month, day)
print d.strftime("%d %B %Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using Python's `datetime` module for this:

```
from datetime import datetime
entered_date = input('Input a date in mm/dd/yy format!\nIf you would like to enter a 1-digit number, enter a zero first, then the number\nDate:')

d = datetime.strptime(entered_date, '%m/%d/%y')
entered_date = d.strftime('%B, %d, %Y')
```

e.g.

```
'February, 29, 2016'
```

This way you catch invalid dates (such as 02/29/15) as well as badly-formatted ones.